# Using MediaRecorder for record Video in Html5

Tags: html, record, mediarecorder, getusermedia

I want to record video from chrome in android device and saved it locally. I use getUserMedia and MediaRecorder from this link (https://addpipe.com/media-recorder-api-demo/), but when I start recording, preview is lagging. any solution?
Is there another solution for record video?

Regards.

Comment: In my experience this is a case of the technology being ahead of the browsers. I have a similar script to record MP3 via the microphone and it's unstable in anything except Chrome, and even then only for samples of less than 30 seconds long. It's far better on mobile devices, though.

Comment: File a bug on Chrome? Worked perfectly in Firefox for Android. Please don't link to a site that wants to scan your face and asks users to hold up the back of a credit card in front of their face.